# Prometheus query_range function is not working properly

Tags: prometheus

I am running the query below to parse the data from Prometheus but getting

> "error": "cannot parse \"\" to a valid timestamp"

```
curl -G -v --data-urlencode 'query=sum(irate(istio_requests_total{reporter="source",destination_service="$service",response_code!~"5.*"}[5m])) / sum(irate(istio_requests_total{reporter="source",destination_service=~"$service"}[5m]))&start=1574750639&end=1574751539&step=15s' 'localhost:9090/api/v1/query_range' | jq
```

result:

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "errorType": "bad_data",
  "error": "cannot parse \"\" to a valid timestamp"
}
```

on the other hand when I am running below query, I am getting the proper result:

```
curl -G -v --data-urlencode 'query=sum(irate(istio_requests_total{reporter="source",destination_service="$service",response_code!~"5.*"}[5m])) / sum(irate(istio_requests_total{reporter="source",destination_service=~"$service"}[5m]))' 'localhost:9090/api/v1/query' | jq
```

result:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "resultType": "vector",
    "result": [
      {
        "metric": {},
        "value": [
          1574761076.19,
          "1"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

can anyone let me know where I am making mistake?.

Answer (score 0):

Your Prometheus Query looks ok, but the `curl` command seems incorrect. Splitting up each query paramater with a `--data-urlencode` is recommended.

```
curl --data-urlencode 'query=queryValue' \
     --data-urlencode 'start=startValue' \
     --data-urlencode 'end=endValue' \
     --data-urlencode 'step=stepValue'
```

So your `curl` call would be:

```
curl -G -v --data-urlencode 'query=sum(irate(istio_requests_total{reporter="source",destination_service="$service",response_code!~"5.*"}[5m])) / sum(irate(istio_requests_total{reporter="source",destination_service=~"$service"}[5m]))' --data-urlencode 'start=1574750639' --data-urlencode 'end=1574751539' --data-urlencode 'step=15s' 'localhost:9090/api/v1/query_range' | jq
```

### Sources

Man Page for `--data-urlencode`
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode

Mentions that it behaves similarly to `-d, --data` https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d

Which talks about using the cli flag multiple times.

> If any of these options is used more than once on the same command line, the data pieces specified will be merged together with a separating &-symbol. Thus, using '-d name=daniel -d skill=lousy' would generate a post chunk that looks like 'name=daniel&skill=lousy'.